# Should I use header-only classes or lib files?

Tags: c++, class

I am creating an external library for general use. What Im asking is should I put every class in just .hpp files like boost does or should I compile it into a lib file and keep the two file per class rule. As far as I can see .hpp is used for speed, so you don't have to add a .lib for every class or a massive one for the whole thing and for cross-platform.

[edit] Whats your personal preference and why. My library would just be for my personal use.
[edit] For statically linking the library

Comment: This will totally depend on more factors than can possibly be named. Do whatever makes sense. Do you want to give them the source? Or do you want them to link against a binary. Those are the 2 basic options.

Comment: Static linking or dynamic linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on if you have cross-platform or templated code. You may not have an awful lot of choice about making the majority in header files if you need a lot of preprocessing to generate it. Otherwise, you should pre-compile as much as possible, as a general rule.

Answer (score 3):

For a class that is used in multiple compilation units (cpp-files) you will want to have as tiny header files as possible to keep down the build time. The bulk of your code should go into a cpp file.

Comment: No, for a static library the bulk should go into many tiny source files, so linking with the library only links in the necessary functions.

Comment: That's only true for certain linkers, I think. The MS toolchain (2008), for example, removes unreferenced functions when compiling to object files with /Gy and linking the exe with /OPT:REF.